# Calculate sum/average of variable within each group of neighboring counties using R

Tags: r, sf, average, county, spdep

I am trying to calculate the sum and/or average value of a variable for each group of neighboring counties in the US. I realized this needs at least two steps:

1. For every county, find the set of neighboring counties.
2. Find average/sum of variable within each group of neighboring counties.

To use the North Carolina SIDS dataset as an example:

```
library(sf)
library(spdep)
library(dplyr)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package="spData")[1], quiet=TRUE)

st_crs(nc) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27"
row.names(nc) <- as.character(nc$FIPSNO)
```

I find the set of neighboring counties for every county in `nc` dataset as follows:

```
neighbors <- poly2nb(nc, queen=TRUE)
```

I wish to find the sum and average of the variable `BIR74` (from the `nc` dataset) in each group of neighboring counties. So if there are 100 counties in the original dataset, there will be 100 groups of neighboring counties, one for each original county.

A) How can I do this using the `nb` list `neighbors`? I haven't been able to find anything on how to move from an `nb` object (which is essentially a list and not a polygon file) and calculate some function of a variable in the original sf object.

B) How can I merge the neighboring group sums/averages back with the original `nc` sf object?

Answer (score 1):

The `neighbors` object is a list, so the neighbours of the first and second polygons in `nc` are:

```
> neighbors[[1]]
[1]  2 18 19
> neighbors[[2]]
[1]  1  3 18
```

So do something over elements of that list, use `sapply` and a function, maybe like this:

```
> sapply(neighbors, function(n){sum(nc$BIR74[n])})
  [1]  4956  7425 18372   807  7352  3165  2566  4611 12629 35679 13841 35361
 [13] 27589 13840  4038 14339  1190 16439  8627  2809   904 11122 23538 30931
 [25] 33418 32556 30934  9020 16879 22521 31817  3497 17974 15910 10897 17365
 [37] 24482 10395 45218 27381 16648 41925 22164  6151  1328 16302 31917 43422
 [49] 24279 18568 21927 19736 12330 37045 13845   846 14381  4465 19023  8070
 [61] 21007 17668 48420 23549 48934  4755 40259 23383 36604 23901 20957 14323
 [73]  2499 21531 13342 28670  5566  3544 40272  8560  1496 20614 25512 29613
 [85] 10285 35914  4451 26216  9225  1824 14909 14787  6703 29247 17604 35858
 [97] 29505 13080  3409 10104
```

That's a vector you can put back into `nc` like `nc$BIR74_NB_SUM = sapply(....`

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue a few months ago working on a project and ended up developing a package to do just that.

I just now published the package on [GitHub](https://github.com/nbrvalues/nbrvalues) and can be installed in R by running `devtools::install_github("nbrvalues/nbrvalues")`. It requires `spdep`. Hope it helps. For your specific question, you would want to use `nbrs_sum()` and `nbrs_mean()` like the example below:

`your_sf <- nbrs_sum(your_sf, unique_id_col="unique_identifier", variable="input_var", date_col="optional_date_if_panel_data")`

`your_sf <- nbrs_mean(your_sf, unique_id_col="unique_identifier", variable="input_var", date_col="optional_date_if_panel_data")`

You can also add list of neighbors to the sf object to double check:

`your_sf <- nbrs_list(your_sf, unique_id_col="unique_identifier")`

Comment: I should have noted above that running the function as shown above will automatically add a new column to the "SF" object, while keeping the original data.